# minikube service url doesn't work with url by command "minikube service list"

Tags: minikube, podman

I installed podman and minikube on my macpro m2, and I deployed several microservices, here is the url that I get using "minikube service list"

| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | customers | No node port |  |
| default | gateway | http/8080 | http://192.168.49.2:31080 |
| default | kubernetes | No node port |  |
| default | vets | No node port |  |
| default | visits | No node port |  |
| default | web | No node port |  |
| kube-system | kube-dns | No node port |  |
| kubernetes-dashboard | dashboard-metrics-scraper | No node port |  |
| kubernetes-dashboard | kubernetes-dashboard | No node port |  |

However, I can't open url http://192.168.49.2:31080  in browser to verify my deployment.

all my pods are running well.

```
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
customers-7cd87b8fc-fbnnn   1/1     Running   3 (67m ago)   124m
gateway-69bb445854-p5ckn    1/1     Running   3 (67m ago)   124m
vets-6745994d46-w2xt8       1/1     Running   3 (67m ago)   124m
visits-cb6899f5d-7vz58      1/1     Running   3 (67m ago)   121m
web-6cbdb88468-tqbdm        1/1     Running   3 (67m ago)   124m
```

here is my yml file of gateway

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gateway
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gateway
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gateway-service
          image: spring2go/spring-petclinic-cloud-gateway:1.0.0.RELEASE
          env:
            - name: SERVER_PORT
              value: "8080"
            - name: WEB_APP_ENDPOINT
              value: http://web:8080
            - name: VETS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
              value: http://vets:8080
            - name: VISITS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
              value: http://visits:8080
            - name: CUSTOMERS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
              value: http://customers:8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway
  labels:
    svc: gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: gateway
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 31080
  type: NodePort
```

Thanks for your kindly help to answer my question，i am a freshman on k8s

Answer (score 0):

seems this is a common problem in docker and macos with apple silicon m1/m2

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13788#issuecomment-1068640594

However the solution doesn't work for me, anyone know the solution, pls. kindly reply here, thanks.